# Padding issues in Tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, padding, tumblr

So I was designing some stuff for a Tumblr theme, and I came across a very annoying problem. I was coding the Reblog and Like buttons, and the Reblog button works fine, but for some reason the Like button gives itself like an extra 5px of padding on the bottom. It is not really a serious problem, but it's really annoying to me because  I cannot find a way to get rid of it. I tried changing height, max height, positioning and all, and nothing got rid of the extra space at the bottom. It may be some stupid mistake on my part, or maybe It's just supposed to be like that, and I'm not realizing it because it's too late, but any help would be nice.
Here is my test blog too in which I have the theme set up. If you look at the source, or mouseover the Like button you can see.
http://mchickenposts.tumblr.com/

Edit: I could just extend the length of thee li, and add the cursor property so the bottom 5px isn't left out. But I wanted to know How i can get rid of it totally.

Here is my Html Code for the Posts, and the Css too.

```
.post_reblog_like{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
.post_reblog_like li{
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:.7;
}
.post_reblog_like li:hover{
    opacity:1;
} 
{block:Text}
                <div class="post_wrapper">
                    <div class="post_text">
                        <div class="post_text_body">
                            {block:Title}
                                <a class="PostTitle" href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>
                            {/block:Title}
                            {block:NoteCount}
                                <a class="post_notes" href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
                                {/block:NoteCount}
                            <div class="PostBody">{Body}</div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="post_date">
                                {block:Date} 
                                    <a title="{DayOfWeek}, {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} @ {12Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}" class="post_date_text" href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>
                                {/block:Date}
                                <ul onmouseover="changeClass();" class="post_reblog_like">
                                    <li title="Reblog">{ReblogButton color="white" size="20"}</li>
                                    <li title="Like">{LikeButton color="white" size="20"}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/block:Text}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to `line-height` (currently there is none defined).

```
.like_button {
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, But it still was exactly the same .-. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: I tried that again, But it's the same. Like The bottom of the button extends 5px down, and when i mouseover that part it displays the title, but when I mouseover the actually heart icon it doesn't display it. And it doesn't  do that with the reblog, and they're both styled exactly the same.

Comment: That is odd, here is how firebug sees the element with the above css: http://i.imgur.com/4EwnmSB.png. The `like_button` won't display a title as it is sadly a `div`, not an `anchor` like the `reblog_button`.

Comment: Yeah I was checking over the source, and when i would set the height and width and stuff it all fits right in, and it should be like 5 px out, but for some reason it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.like_button` to a `display: block` and then `float: left`. Elements with `display:` `inline` and `inline-block` always add some space at the bottom for letters like 'y' or 'g'. Hope it helps someone!